# GetAsyncKeyState shift activates the "p" key

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard

I am capturing keystates. The problem is, when I press lshift or rshift, also the "p"
key is activated. I've tested and the problem doesn't come from the rest of my code, so it would be useless to post more than this:

```
for(int x=6; x<254; x++)
{
if (GetAsyncKeyState(x) >> 15)
    {
    key[x] = 1;
    key2[x] = 1;
    }
}
```

I've tested physical state of P using this:

```
for(int x=6; x<254; x++)
{
if (GetAsyncKeyState(x) >> 15)
    {
            key[x]= 1;
            keyp[x] = 1;        
            if (x == VK_SHIFT)
            {
                std::cout << std::bitset<8>(GetAsyncKeyState(80) >> 15);
            }
    } 
    }
```

And I've found that, when I press shift, the p key doesn't **immediately** activate. The high bit of P is still 0 for two ticks, than turns on.
Anybody's got any clue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that bit-shift of a signed value (which is what `GetAsyncKeyState` returns) is undefined behavior.

Comment: What happens if you replace that `>> 15` with `& 0xFFFF8000`? That should have the same effect: getting rid of the low 15 bits.